# how to convert the date format: 2020-09-28T11:47:37.217 to just 11:47?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I receive the following date/time format through api call:

```
"AcceptedDate": "2020-09-28T11:47:37.217",
"Pickup1ArrivedDate": "2020-10-06T17:28:12.6",
"Pickup1LoadedDate": "2020-10-06T17:57:54.84",
"Pickup1DepartedDate": "2020-10-06T18:18:59.927"
```

Is there anyway to show the time in the format"11:47" after saving the response in java/android studio.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the next 5 characters after the letter T

```
    String date = "2020-09-28T11:47:37.217";
    int from = date.indexOf("T")+1;
    int to = from+5;
    
    String timeOfInterest = date.substring(from, to);
    System.out.println( timeOfInterest );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring()` to create a method to do so:

```
 public String stripRedundantDate(String date){
     return date.substring(11, 16);
 }
```

The following program:

```
public class Main{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String time = "2020-09-28T11:47:37.217";
        System.out.println(stripRedundantDate(time));
     }
     public static String stripRedundantDate(String date){
         return date.substring(11, 16);
     }
}
```

Produces the result:

```
11:47
```

**If your date is not a fixed length**

Use the following:

```
 public static String stripRedundantDate(String date){
     return date.substring(date.indexOf(':')-2, date.indexOf(':')+3);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert it to a date object and then work with it that way

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(apiResult.get("AcceptedDate"));
```

Then I would format it to look how you want:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

String dateString = format.format( date  ); // this string will be the time you are looking for
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Also from your first code line I get `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-09-28T11:47:37.217' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10`. You should use `LocalDateTIme` (not `LocalDate`)  for parsing the string.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't know how to format a `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin**

```
fun formatDate(date: String): String {
        val input = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.ENGLISH)
        val output = SimpleDateFormat("12:08 PM", Locale.ENGLISH)
        return output.format(input.parse(date)!!)
    }
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 0):

### java.time either through desugaring or through ThreeTenABP

I suggest you consider using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

```
    String acceptedDate = "2020-09-28T11:47:37.217";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(acceptedDate);
    String timeString = dateTime.toLocalTime()
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)
            .toString();
    System.out.println(timeString);
```

Output is:

> 11:47

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.